# How to insert new line between two characters found in regex

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm am trying to clean up a file that does not seem to write each new log entry on a new line. Some entries end up getting appended to the end of the previous line. This makes it difficult when I try to analyze and get correct counts/data using grep/awk, etc...

This is what each line/entry looks like - note I've replaced the actual contents of the log entry but basically each entry starts with same string and end with the same pattern, an ID/string followed by a number, ex "ID: 20".

Pattern:

```
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: ##
```

(Note the number after ID is not always the same for each entry)

What happens is some lines of the file end up having two entries on the same line:

```
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 33
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 20INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 55
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 20
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 27INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 14
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 35INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 22
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 10
```

What I would like to do is a new line on that second row above, between the "ID: ##" and "INFO" for all the lines impacted in my files.

I can grep all the links that this occurs in by `grep "ID: [0-9]*INFO" mylog.log`

and have tried a number of sed commands but cant seem to figure out how to sneak that new line '\n' between a number [0-9]* and INFO...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the posted sample input/output all you need is this with a sed that has `-E` to enable EREs and support `\n` in the replacement text as meaning "newline" (e.g. GNU and OSX/BSD seds):

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]+)INFO/\1\nINFO/g' file
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 33
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 20
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: ##
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 20
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 27
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: ##
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 35
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 22
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 10
```

or this otherwise with any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)INFO/\1\
INFO/g' file
```

If that doesn't work for you then fix your example to include cases where that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` you can do this:

```sh
grep -Eo 'INFO:[[:blank:]].*?ID:[[:blank:]][0-9]+' file

INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 33
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 20
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 55
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 20
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 27
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 14
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 35
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 22
INFO: DATA: ## DATA2 ## DATA3: ##.### DATA4: ## ID: 10
```

Comment: `.*?` looks kinda PCRE-ish to me. It's undefined behavior in an ERE at least.

Comment: "undefined" doesn't mean it won't produce the output you expect from some input using some version of the tool in some shell on some Unix box, it just means you can/will have different results in different situations depending on how the tool implementers decided to implement that non-POSIX functionality.

Comment: FWIW when I run that command using GNU grep in bash on cygwin it outputs the unmodified input.

Comment: With `gnu grep` I believe we need to use `-P` instead of `-E`

Comment: Right, `.*?` is a PCRE-ism and `-P` enables PCREs in GNU grep. It's just undefined what any grep that doesn't have an option to enable PCREs will do with `.*?`. The option `-E` doesn't enable PCREs, only EREs, so then YMMV with that lust like if you didn't use `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

one lazy method for this is first insert new line whenever you notice "INFO" not at left most position, then pipe it to a regex pattern checker to ensure it fits the DATA...DATA4 bill.